# npm version without a git-tag

Tags: git, npm, release, package.json

I'd like to run

```
npm version from-git
```

to sync the latest git tag and package.json version after a release. The issue is that this creates a git tag, and since it's pulled from the latest tag, it fails because that tag already exist. Is there a way to set the package.json version to the new git tag, commit and push that, without creating the git tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off commit and tag by setting `npm config set git-tag-version false` or use `npm --no-git-tag-version version` to do it on a per-command basis. It will just update package.json and package-lock.json without either committing or creating a tag. You can then commit the changes as you see fit.

If you want to update the version and commit in one command you can do:

```
NEW_VERSION=$(npm --no-git-tag-version version from-git) && git commit -am "Bump version to $NEW_VERSION"
```

If you want to push as well you can do:

```
NEW_VERSION=$(npm --no-git-tag-version version from-git) && git commit -am "Bump version to $NEW_VERSION" && git push
```